# Upload a video do not work with the YouTube API v3

Tags: c#, .net

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
        Console.WriteLine("==============================");

        try
        {
            new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                //
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.

                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
        var filePath = "video2.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                break;

            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                break;
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }
```

But i am getting progress.Status is Failed every time.I am unable to upload a video to youtube. My video file size is 2MB.and I am create clientid and secret key for webapplication in https://console.developers.google.com. Can any one help me to resolve this please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You was created clientid and secret key for webapplication.
Must create key for installed. And download the JSON file.
Rename the JSON file name to "client_secrets.json".
And save to bin/Debug ot bin/Release as same *.exe as directory.